# Автоматический перезапуск консольной команды

Tags: php, linux

Использую в проекте сокеты, скрипт (php) запускается через консоль и слушает сокет. Как можно запустить автоматически скипт в случае падения?( linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 вариант - Supervisor http://supervisord.org/
2 вариант - поставить в cron периодическую задачу-скрипт, который проверяет наличие процесса скрипта и, при отсутствии, запускает

Comment: Первым вариантом воспользовался

Answer (score 0):

просто перезапускайте в бесконечном цикле.

т.е. вместо:

```
$ программа аргументы
```

пишите:

```
$ while :; do программа аргументы; done
```

а чтобы несколько снизить вред системе в случае, когда программа при старте сразу же «падает», имеет смысл добавить задержку между перезапусками. ну хотя бы в одну секунду:

```
$ while :; do программа аргументы; sleep 1; done
```

Comment: Ну хотя бы sleep 1 для приличия поставить, а то какой-нибудь глобальный глюк обернётся DoS-атакой на самого себя)

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо, добавил.